# How to build a backward-compatible System Preferences pane?

Tags: xcode, macos, memory-management, system-preferences

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PreferencePanes/Articles/UpdatingPreferencePanes.html) says that System Preferences panes should be 64-bit programs, and that in OS 10.6 and 10.7, a 64-bit preference pane is expected to use garbage collection.  But for 10.8, they say to use ARC, and recent versions of Xcode don't allow building with garbage collection.  How can I make a System Preferences pane compatible with any OS from 10.7 through 10.12?